# Is it possible to run vb.net on Window CE?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 VB.NET to develop an application, and it is working fine in Window XP SP3. Is it possible to run this application on a mobile device with Window CE 6.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application will not directly run on Windows CE, no.  Since you're using Studio 2008, create a new Smart Device Project from the New Project wizard and import your existing code base.

Since you started with a desktop project, it's unlikely that the code will just compile as-is but, depending on exactly what features you're using, it's quite possible that you'll be able to modify what you have to compile for both the Compact Framework (CF) and the full framework.

Comment: so, when the code are not supported in Smart Device Project, it will be an error, right?

Comment: Yes, once you import the code into a Smart Device project, unsupported calls will be flagged as errors by the compiler.